# Python noob I need help in loops

Tags: python, loops

import time

```
print ('Hi!')
time.sleep(1)
print('my name is Magiting')
time.sleep(1)
myname = "Magiting"
realname = 'Uldarico'
while true:
        name = str(input("What's yours? "))
if name == myname:
 print("Nope, that's my name")
 print("Try again")
elif name == realname:
 print ('I dont want to do this, SPY!')
 print ('line disconnected...')
break
else:
 print (name+ "? That's quite a unique name")
 print ('...')

time.sleep(1)
print ('So, '+ name + ', what can I do for you?')
```

This is my code and I have changed it time and time again but I just can't seem to loop the first statement to the input and the second statement into breaking while the third continues.

Comment: The first thing you should learn is that indentation matters **a lot** in Python

Comment: Please give more details about what is the problem you have and the behavior you expect. It's unclear.

Comment: while true: ===> while True:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
print ('Hi!')
time.sleep(1)
print('my name is Magiting')
time.sleep(1)
myname = "Magiting"
realname = 'Uldarico'
while True:
    name = raw_input("What's yours? ")
    if name == myname:
        print("Nope, that's my name")
        print("Try again")
    elif name == realname:
        print ('I dont want to do this, SPY!')
        print ('line disconnected...')
        break
    else:
        print (name+ "? That's quite a unique name")
        print ('...')

time.sleep(1)
print ('So, '+ name + ', what can I do for you?')
```

Comment: As seen above, @Johnny Kuo made several edits: 0) changed true to True; 1) provided proper indenting. With Python, indentation is critically important to helping the Python interpreter understand where a code block begins and ends. Code blocks are used with while loops, for loops, if/elif/else statements and more.